# How to not forget your active items

Tags: league-of-legends

Many items in League Of Legends have active effects which can be cast like normal spells.

Those active effects increase the gold efficiency of an item, if they are used and the base stats of those items often have a gold efficiency below 100%. So not using the active effect is wasted gold.

How can I get myself into using the actives of items?

Comment: Not enough to be an answer, but i'll share a tip that I found to be just amazing ! Bind your Blade of the ruined King on Vayne to her W, as it is only a passive, it will perfectly fit on her kit, and will feel just like a normal spell !

Comment: @Shunwoo great tipp! also works with ghostblade ;-)

Comment: I would rephrase the title to something like "How to not forget your active items",because using them when you really need them is worth WAY more then to use them just for the sake of button pressing. using items more often does not equal making the best use of items.

Comment: @gruntswilldie true! i will rephrase it soon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the actives of items takes a lot of practice and there is no "do that and you will use the actives more often"

However, there are tipps I can give to you which make it some kind of a habit to use them:

### Assign them always to the same hotkey

When building items, always try to assing them to the same slot depending on the champion. This makes your brain think they are just another skill for e certain champion.

What I like to do is use QWER for my normal skills, 1 2 3 4 for my active items, T for my trinket, 5 for items that place Stealthwards and 6 for Vision Wards.

Muscle memory is a huge factor when it come to LoL, especially with skills and actives.

You can drag items to the slot you want by holding down the left mousebutton when hovering them, drag them over the slot you want and release the mousebutton. You often have to drag the items a little away from your inventory to make the drag animation appear.

### Always keep an eye on their cooldown

Its the same thing like looking on the map now and then to see whats going on, looking at your R cooldown or at the timers for baron and dragon. "Just" add your Item slots to your screen-looking-rotation and you will remind yourself of the items you have.

### Replace champion skills that are just passives

Bind your Blade of the ruined King on Vayne to her W, as it is only a passive, it will perfectly fit on her kit, and will feel just like a normal spell.
**(thanks to [shunwoo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/84398/shunwoo) for this tipp)**

Comment: Binding to an ability seems counter-productive to the muscle memory, since it won't be there on all champion, so the memory of hitting `W` will be lost on all but those champions you can do it. Better work on a fixed pattern for muscle memory.

Comment: i disagree on that. as long as you do the same thing for each champion, you will develop muscle memory. muscle memory is bound to a certain champion, just like combos.

Comment: The thing is that if you play any champion where you bind the item to an ability key and then switch to one that doesn't, your memory will want you to hit the ability key to use the item since that's what you've been doing before. Eventually, yes, you'll have trained your memory to act differently on different champs but it is counter-productive while fixed pattern will be easier overall.

Comment: disagree on that too. you dont press Q and expect your champ to throw a spear just because you played pantheon the game before. some champs harras with W (ashe) and some with Q (Ezreal) and your brain is able to do that transition. you associate champs and there hotkey position with each other, not the effect of a spelleffect with the hotkey position. but hey :) do it as you like, I'm just giving my tipps

Answer (score 0):

Binding the item to an ability key feels short sighted, it will help you on that specific champion but won't solve your overall problem. The key trick is to always assign the item to the same slot and then practice using it as part of your main combo.

For example I always put sightstone/wards in slot 5. Trinkets as slot 4. Defensive items as 3 offensive items as 1. Now train to using that item and including it as part of your combo. When you Crowstorm in as Fiddlesticks you're running and positioning and casting your other spells but you will automatically Zhonyas when the time comes because it's part of that combo and you are ready to do it.

Equally an assassin that opens with BotRK, or a Darius or Talon that includes a Hydra activation in their combo - just by having that combination and using it repeatedly you will learn to use more and more.

The biggest improvements I've seen in my own play is just coming from playing champions that use items a lot and then trying to remember to use them and kicking myself if I forget!